# what units do Mouse.move() use?

Tags: mouse

When I use Mouse.move() method (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseMove), what are units of xVal and yPos parameters?

Answer (score 1):

They're raw HID counts and as such don't have a unit. It is up to the OS to translate them from logical amounts to physical values.